# Are they real in the movie Revolver?

Tags: plot-explanation, revolver

Are Zack and Avi real in the movie Revolver or are they Mr.Green's imagination?

Comment: Isn't Revolver a hardcore gangster flick? Do you have any reason to suspect they're figments of his imagination and not real people? It seems like a weird thing for a movie like that to do.

Comment: Oh no, it's far from being a simple gangster flick. The violence is only on the surface.

Comment: @F1Krazy Revolver is something of a departure for Guy Ritchie.  It *is* a hardcore gangster flick, but there's also a healthy dose of mindfork.  I recall wondering whether or not these two characters were real when I watched it myself, although it's been so long that I don't recall where I landed ;)